# algorithm that determine whether there exists a duplicate integer with expected runtime $O(n)$

Tags: algorithms

Consider an input of unsorted array; we want to determine whether exists a duplicate integer; the algorithm should have expected runtime $O(n)$.

Note: We want to analysis the expected runtime by counting the number of comparisons in the algorithm.

I know that the brute force requires $\Theta(n^2)$ complexity and the best case is $\Theta(1)$.

However, for expected runtime analysis; is this equivalent to average case ? Where we consider all possible of runtime complexity and taking expectation over them?

Since the algorithm will be based on the number of comparisons we make.

the all possible number of comparisons we will make would be a set 
$\{1,2,3,4,...,n-1,n,n+1,...,2n-3, ......\}$ (where $1,..,n-1$, are number of comparisons might be made when compare $A[0]$ to others, and so on; and $n$ is size of array); then taking expectation, but how do I decide the probability of each number of comparisons? For example, if the algorithm terminates with only one comparison, then $A[0] == A[1]$, but I don't how do I determine this probability ?

Comment: thanks for the mention; I have fixed it

Comment: What are the elements of your input array? I read your question as meaning they were arbitrary integers. Or are the integers bounded?

Comment: @RobArthan they just positive integer without bound

Comment: @j4nbur53 yes, sorry for the unclarity

Comment: So for $n=2$, you want an algorithm that can determine whether two integers _of arbitrary size_ are equal in constant time? That is obviously not possible.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I mean that the best case occurs when first two integer are duplicate, then algorithm terminates when doing the first comparison; then no matter how long the array is, the best is constant time; that's my understanding of best case run time

Comment: @Ellery: Yes, but the default assumption when we're talking about complexity is that we're interested in the _worst_ case complexity. And in the worst case, when you're comparing two integers, you may need to _read the entire input_ before you can be sure whether they're equal or not.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Oh, I see, but we assume that input is in the memory; by brute force, the algorithm dominated by the number of comparisons

Comment: @ElleryL: That doesn't matter. If the input is in memory, you still need to _inspect every bit of the input_ before you can be sure whether the two numbers are equal or not. There's no way around that. I'm not talking about I/O, simply about the fact that your algorithm needs to process every bit of the input -- if it doesn't, an adversary will be able to construct an input that fools it.

Comment: As you say at the end, you don't have enough information to find out the probability of the first comparison "succeeding" and terminating the algorithm.  More assumptions are needed to impose a probability distribution and obtain the "expected" runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) search and insert are usually both considered $O(1)$ in the average. So if you start with an empty hash table, go through all the elements search and insert at the same time, you find the element in the average at index $k=(n+1)/2$ assuming there is only one duplicate, so you need $O(n)$ hash computations and equality comparisons (inside the hash table) or less.

If you dont use a hash table, but an ordinary list, checking for the collision is $O(m)$ where m is the length of the ordinary list, assuming we dont detect a collision. Taking again the average under the same distribution as before we get $1/6\,n\,(n + 2)$. So you would then need $O(n^2)$ equality comparisons (inside the ordinary list) or less.

The different program codes look very similar (in Java):

Hash table:

```
HashSet res = new HashSet();
for (int i=0; i<A.size(); i++) {
    if (res.contains(A.get(i))     /* O(1) */
      return true;
    res.add(A.get(i));             /* O(1) */
}
return false;
```

Ordinary list:

```
ArrayList res = new ArrayList();
for (int i=0; i<A.size(); i++) {
    if (res.contains(A.get(i))     /* O(m) */
      return true;
    res.add(A.get(i));             /* O(1) */
}
return false;
```

We can now make the probability model I was using more explicit. I am using a random variable $X$, for the number of iterations of the outer for loop. The variable is in the range $\{0, .., n\}$, $0$ means a duplicate was found in the first iteration and true was return. $n$ means no duplicate was found and false was return.

I did work with $P[X=i] = 1/(n+1)$ an uniform distribution. The effort of the programm can be viewed as the expected value $E[Y]$ of another random variable $Y = f(X)$, that computes the effort for performing the loop X times. For the hash table we have $Y = X$, and for the ordinary list we have $Y = 1/2\,X\,(X+1)$, neglecting the add() and only considering the contains().

Hash table:
$$E[Y]=E[X]=\sum_{i=0}^n P[X=i] i=\frac{1}{n+1} \frac{1}{2} n (n+1)=\frac{1}{2} n$$
Ordinary list:
$$E[Y]=E[\frac{1}{2} X (X+1)]=\sum_{i=0}^n P[X=i] \frac{1}{2} i (i+1)=\frac{1}{n+1} \frac{1}{6} n (n + 1) (n + 2) = \frac{1}{6} n (n+2)$$

The distribution that was chosen can be viewed as an upper bound, distributions that are more realistic or that also consider that there are multiple duplicates, would give a higher weight to lower values of $X$, which also means a higher weight to lower values of $Y = f(X)$, and thus in the end a lower value of $E[Y]$.

Comment: thanks for the advice of hashtable with direct address;  but can you explain more about the expected run time with the brutal force as well ?

Comment: Brute force, is just using an ordinary list, you get O(n^2) and not O(n). The better formula is 1/6 n (n + 2), but the dominant term is also n^2.

Comment: What does "hash table insert is usually considered $O(1)$ on average" mean? That sounds like nonsense to me.

Comment: See the wikipedia article that I have linked. A full fledge hash table has a load factor, expands itself from time to time and has linked lists, for where the hash collides but the key is still distinct. This gives around amortized O(1) for contains() and add(), as if you were using the key as a direct address.

Comment: But the metric is such that we count computing the hash value and doing the comparison, even if big objects are involved, as one step. As the OP asked "We want to analysis the expected runtime by counting the number of comparisons in the algorithm." Which is a simplification and in reality, for example when using bignums, this is not true.

Comment: BTW: The Java implementation can only grow, it has only a high water mark. This implementation of mine has also a low water mark, and can shrink as well: https://github.com/jburse/jekejeke-devel/blob/master/utils/headless/matula/util/data/SetHash.java

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that each of the input numbers are represented as a particular string of symbols from a finite alphabet, you can build a [*trie*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) representing the numbers you have seen so far, while reading them. That will automatically detect duplicates for you, while doing a constant amount of work per input symbol.

Comment: Your method will automatically detect duplicates, but will it do so in $O(1)$ expected time on reading each new input?

Comment: @RobArthan: Yes -- assuming that the input alphabet is fixed in advance,

Comment: @HenningMakholm: And that the input *length* is bounded by a fixed constant, although I suppose at that point we're pressing into the question of what precisely we are counting.

Comment: @Hurkyl: No, that is not necessary. I'm assuming the standard convention that the $n$ in $O(n)$ measures the _number of symbols_ in the input.

Comment: @j4nbur53: The standard assumption here is that a pointer large enough to represent any location in the input can be manipulated in constant time.

Comment: @j4nbur53: Or if you want to be even more formal about it, assume a RAM where the constant-time operations are incrementing or decrementing a register by _one_, and the input is given in a sequence of registers initialized to $0$ or $1$ each.

Comment: @j4nbur53: In the model of my last comment, register values can be as large as you want, except that the only way to create a large integer is to count up to it one by one. (The machine must have instructions to _copy_ values between memory locations).

Comment: @j4nbur53: The cost model usually assumed (the one that leads to the familiar textbook asymptotics for standard algorithms) assumes I can. You can define a different model if you want to, but it won't be the standard one -- and then something like "you can decide whether a string is a palindrome in linear time" which intuitively ought to be true, are probably not true in that model anymore.

Comment: @j4nbur53: Correct -- but that just says that a Turing machine is not a useful model for reasoning about the time complexity of algorithms that run on real computers. (Turing machines would never even be mentioned in complexity, were it not for the remarkable and unexpected fact the "polynomial time" does turn out to be the same complexity class between Turing machines and more realistic models. Lower than that, Turing machine timing doesn't have much practical significance).

Answer (score 2):

The algorithm depends very much on the nature of the input.

If the input consists of $n$ integers of some bounded size, then we can consider each integer as a single symbol from a possibly quite large, but finite alphabet. Let there be $k$ symbols in the alphabet; then $k$ is a fixed constant for any input, and any input of length $>k$ contains a duplicate by the pigeonhole principle.

For example, if the input is an array of any length containing $32$-bit integers, then $k=2^{32}.$

The algorithm for this kind of problem begins by counting up to $k+1$ integers in the input. If the count reaches $k+1,$ the algorithm returns "a duplicate exists"; otherwise it performs up to $k(k-1)$ comparisons (the brute force method). So in the worst case we have $k+1$ steps of counting and $k(k-1)$ comparisons; but since $k$ is a fixed constant, the running time of the algorithm is bounded, and the entire algorithm runs in worst-case $O(1)$ time. (The time constant for that $O(1)$ time may be quite large, however.)

A more interesting kind of input allows the integers of input to be strings of digits of any length. Now we have to say what it means to have an input of size $n$; a reasonable interpretation is that $n$ is the sum of the lengths of all the strings (or the sum of the lengths plus the number of strings, to allow for demarcation of the strings). Then Henning Makholm's solution (using a trie) runs in $O(n)$ worst-case time, which implies it has $O(n)$ expected time.

Another possible interpretation is that we allow the integers to be strings of arbitrary length, but we assume there is some probability distribution that governs the value of each integer. That is, if $m$ is a given integer, then there is some probability $P(m)$ that the next input integer will equal $m.$

In that interpretation there is some fixed probability $P_0$ that two integers selected at random from the input will be the same. The expected length of an integer (a bound on the expected time required to compare two integers) is also a fixed value. 
If the first pass of the algorithm merely compares the first and second integers of input, then the third and fourth, then fifth and sixth, etc., then as the length of input goes toward infinity the chance of finding a match approaches $1$ and the expected number of comparisons before finding the match (when there is one) approaches a constant.

The expected number of comparisons when we compare *all* possible pairs of input integers (up to the first matching pair) is a little more complicated to deal with, since the pairs are not all independently distributed, but maybe one can show that it's also bounded as $n$ goes to infinity; if so, the expected running time of the entire algorithm is $O(1).$